# Order on types for type level programming

Tags: rust, type-level-computation

I've dived into type-level programming in Rust, as it could be very helpful to me in one of my projects. However, I am still struggling a little bit with what is possible or not.

Especially, I would like to implement an order on types to sort tuples. This will allow me to use tuples which are "vector" of types as "sets" of types.

So far, I have found how to implement linked list in type level programming, and I can use macros to convert tuples to linked list (and back):

```rust
trait LinkedList {}
// empty list
struct EmptyList;
// list: a head, (element in the list) and tail (rest of the list)
struct ListElem<Head, Tail: List>(PhantomData<(Head, Tail)>);
// empty list is a list
impl LinkedList for EmptyList {}
// list element is a list as well
impl<H, T: List> LinkedList for ListElem<H, T> {}
```

And my conversions: (shown for 2 elements, but I will use macros to generate as many as I want)

```rust
trait TupleToList {
    type List;
}
trait ListToTuple {
    type Tuple;
}
// this can easily be done with macros, for tuples up to a lot
impl<A, B> TupleToList for (A, B) {
    type List = ListElem<A, ListElem<B, EmptyList>>;
}
impl<A, B> ListToTuple for ListElem<A, ListElem<B, EmptyList>> {
    type Tuple = (A, B);
}
```

Now, [This article](https://dev.to/thedenisnikulin/type-level-bubble-sort-in-rust-part-2-43b6) shows type-level buble sort, but for this I need an order on my types, which can be written as :

```rust
struct CompareEQ;
struct CompareLT;
struct CompareGT;
// order between types
trait CompareTypes<T> {
    type Result;
}
// handy shortcut
type TypeOrder<T, U> = <T as CompareTypes<U>>::Result;
```

(As I want a set of types, I could remove the EQ operator as any tuples with duplicate types would be rejected)

My issue is that I have no idea how to order my types. With unstable features such as const traits, const type id I can write an const function that order types, but it is not type level :

```rust
const fn bigger_type_id<T: 'static, U: 'static>() -> bool {
    let t = unsafe {std::mem::transmute::<_, u128>(TypeId::of::<T>()) };
    let u = unsafe {std::mem::transmute::<_, u128>(TypeId::of::<U>()) };
    t < u
}
```

If I want to use this, I need to somehow convert back from value level to type level, something that would look like so:

```
impl<T, U> CompareTypes<U> for T {
    type Result = if bigger_type_id<T, U>() { GT } else { LT };
}
```

(This syntax is not valid)

Also, I could take all types I want to sort and write another macro that write the order for them, but this application is intended for a library, where the user can define it's own types. This means that I would need him to invoke this macro, which I'm not a fan of.

What are my alternatives to implement type-level order on types ?

#### EDIT:

I've tried this out, where I use const generics and compute them with my function:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait BiggerThan<T, const IS_IT: bool> {}

impl<T: 'static, U: 'static> BiggerThan<U, { bigger_type_id::<T, U>() }> for T {}

trait ActuallyBiggerThan<T> {
    type SomeType;
}

impl<T, U: BiggerThan<T, true>> ActuallyBiggerThan<T> for U {
    // Only for some tests
    type SomeType = &'static str;
}

type DoesItWorkOnce = <u8 as ActuallyBiggerThan<bool>>::SomeType;
type DoesItWorkTwice = <bool as ActuallyBiggerThan<u8>>::SomeType;
```

I tried it out with this :

```rust
pub fn func() {
    let v1: DoesItWorkOnce = "Hello";
    let v2: DoesItWorkTwice = "World";
}
```

Unfortunately, both types throw me the error :

"mismatched types
expected constant `true`
found constant `false`"

Which I believe, means that this does not work for some reason ?

I also get a feature warning :
"the feature `generic_const_exprs` is incomplete and may not be safe to use and/or cause compiler crashes" so maybe the feature does not work properly ?

#### EDIT 2:

I made a typo in my first edit, I was asking for U to implement BiggerThan instead of BiggerThan.

Turns out my solution actually works ! (I fixed the typo in the first edit)

Comment: I had the same problem with other languages (C++ and Haskell) back when I tried to implement a particular library for them. I wonder how Rust copes.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I actually found a way to do it, and managed to instaure a ordering on types that can be expressed with a trait for type-level programming ! Take a look at my edits (it requires lot of unstable features however)

Comment: Transmuting `TypeId` to any other type is explicitly UB. Also, what is the meaning of comparing two `TypeId`s beside equality?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am aware of the transmuting UB, but it actually show the underlying u128 (they have the same size, and it is said that type id are u128). Furthermore, the whole point of what I am doing is implementing compile types archetypes for an ecs, so one must know that (String, bool) and (bool, String) are the same archetype, therefore we need a way to sort types in tuples. To do this, we need an order on types. 
I know this is nightly rust, and mostly experimental, but I really enjoy what the languages allows !

Comment: The point is that it is not guaranteed to stay a `u128`.

Comment: I understand, and I'll find proper ways to do this if it becomes a breaking change.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I needed it to implement compile-time sets and maps of types efficiently and elegantly. Not strictly necessary but life is so much nicer with it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yeah, the point of what I'm doing is also set of types (instead of vecs of types, which are what tuples really are). I'm getting more and more into the rabbit hole and type-level programming, and I feel it opens a whole new world of possibilities !

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique I noticed you got a solution working (off-site, at least I think you're the same person, it'd be a crazy coincidence if not); if you can self-answer with your solution here, that'd be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to sort tuples, and I'll post my solution here:

The core question was how to use `const fn` to implement trait, and the trick I found was to use `#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]`:

```rust
const fn t_greater_than_u<T: 'static, U: 'static>() -> bool {
    let t = unsafe {std::mem::transmute::<_, u128>(std::any::TypeId::of::<T>()) };
    let u = unsafe {std::mem::transmute::<_, u128>(std::any::TypeId::of::<U>()) };
    t > u
}

/// Defines an order on types.
trait TypeComparaison<T> {
    const GREATER: bool;
}

impl<T: 'static, U: 'static> TypeComparaison<U> for T {
    const GREATER: bool = { t_greater_than_u::<T, U>() };
}
```

Now, I'll post the rest of the code as a resources for anyone who want to implement sorting in type-level programming:

First define a list structure:

```rust
pub(crate)  trait List {}
pub(crate)  struct Nil;
pub(crate)  struct Cons<Head, Tail: List>(std::marker::PhantomData<(Head, Tail)>);
impl List for Nil {}
impl<H, T: List> List for Cons<H, T> {}
```

Then, we will expand our comparaison to compare a value with a list (with the head of the list) :

```rust
trait CompareTypeList<L: List> {
    const GREATER: bool;
}
impl<T> CompareTypeList<Nil> for T {
    const GREATER: bool = false;
}
impl<T: 'static, Head: 'static, L: List> CompareTypeList<Cons<Head, L>> for T {
    const GREATER: bool = <T as TypeComparaison<Head>>::GREATER;
}
```

We will then define usefull traits (that are functions in type level programming) :

Insertion will allow to insert a type in our list, preserving any order:

```rust
pub(crate) trait Insert<T, const TYPE_GT: bool> { type Output: List; }
impl<T> Insert<T, true> for Nil { type Output = Cons<T, Nil>; }
impl<T> Insert<T, false> for Nil { type Output = Cons<T, Nil>; }
impl<T, Head, L: List> Insert<T, false> for Cons<Head, L> {
    type Output = Cons<T, Cons<Head, L>>;
}
// I'm going to write comments about this : 
// T is the type we want to insert in the list. We implement insert for T on Cons<Head, L>, where T > Head.
// So, we need to create a list where Head is first element, and recursively insert T in the tail of the list.
// for this, T must me comparable with the list L, and L must be insertable with T.
// there we have all our trait bound explained !
impl<T: CompareTypeList<L>, Head, L: List + Insert<T, {<T as CompareTypeList<L>>::GREATER}>> Insert<T, true> for Cons<Head, L> {
    type Output = Cons<Head, <L as Insert<T, {<T as CompareTypeList<L>>::GREATER}>>::Output>;
}
```

We can now sort our List by recursively inserting all elements:

```rust
pub(crate) trait SortList { type SortedList: List; }
// how easy it is to sort an empty list !
impl SortList for Nil { type SortedList = Nil; }
impl<Head, L: List + SortList> SortList for Cons<Head, L>
    where
        Head: CompareTypeList<<L as SortList>::SortedList>, 
        <L as SortList>::SortedList: Insert<Head, {<Head as CompareTypeList<<L as SortList>::SortedList>>::GREATER}>
{
    type SortedList = <<L as SortList>::SortedList as Insert<Head, {<Head as CompareTypeList<<L as SortList>::SortedList>>::GREATER}>>::Output;
}
```

Finally, we need some conversion tuple <=> List. we will simply do this with macros, that will implement a trait that looks like this:

```
pub(crate) trait TupleToList { type List; }
pub(crate) trait ListToTuple { type Tuple; }

impl<A, B> TupleToList for (A, B) { type List = Cons<A, Cons<B, Nil>>; }
impl<A, B> ListToTuple for Cons<A, Cons<B, Nil>> { type Tuple = (A, B); }
```

(I've shown the impl for 2 elems so it's clear, but a macro can implement this for all tuples up to some length)

Finally, we can write our sorting generic:

```
pub(crate) trait TupleSortTrait {
    type Sorted;
}

impl<T> TupleSortTrait for T
where T: TupleToList,
      <T as TupleToList>::List: SortList,
      <<T as TupleToList>::List as SortList>::SortedList: ListToTuple, 
{
    type Sorted = <<<T as TupleToList>::List as SortList>::SortedList as ListToTuple>::Tuple;
}

pub(crate) type TupleSort<T> = <T as TupleSortTrait>::Sorted;
```

This whole thing definitively need some clean up, and as mentionned in the comments I'll try to find a better solution for type ordering than `TypeId`.

But this works, and we can write this kind of things:

```rust
let v = vec![
    <(u8, String, bool) as Default>::default(),
    <TupleSort<(String, bool, u8)> as Default>::default(),
    <TupleSort<(bool, String, u8)> as Default>::default(),
];
```